# Multiple AJAX Status in JSF (PrimeFaces) with multiple forms

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, multiple-forms

I have multiple command buttons in my JSF ... Its a database search which has one 'Search' button and the other 'Add' button.

When clicking on 'Search' Button i wanted a status to be displayed, so i added the below ajaxStatus code to my outputPanel which is in form1 where my search results are displayed.

```
<p:ajaxStatus  onstart="statusDialog1.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog1.hide();"/>
```

**Dialog Box**

```
<p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog1" header="Searching ... Please wait"   
                    draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="False">  
<p:graphicImage value="/resources/ajax-loader.gif" />  
</p:dialog>
```

When the 'Add' button is clicked, another dialog box opens which has form2, now the problem is when i click on 'Add' Button statusDialog1 is shown as well, i want that status to be shown only when 'Search' button is clicked.

How do i use multiple agaxStatus messages in the same page ?

Answer (score 2):

From the [dev guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html)

> AjaxStatus is a global notifier for ajax requests.

In other words, you will have one per page which handles all ajax processing on that page. If you are using PrimeFaces `p:commandButton` you can use the `onstart` and `onsuccess` attribute of your Add and Search button. Example:

```
<p:commandButton value="Add" onstart="statusDialog1.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog1.hide()"/>
<p:commandButton value="Search" onstart="statusDialog2.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog2.hide()"/>
```

Another thing you can use to "show" the ajax status of each component is PrimeFaces `<p:blockUI>`. You can refer to the [showcase for some examples](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml)

Comment: I really like the <p:blockUI> solution. Thank you for this idea.

Comment: @RichardK. Happy to help :)